# Add event on dayClick in resourceWeek view in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have this code:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      height: 300,
      buttons: [
        { text: "Ok", click: function() {
        eventData = getEventSelected(date, resource);
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      { text: "Cancel", click: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
    }
    ]
    });
}
```

With my getEventSelected function I want to make an event, but dayClick does not hold the information about the resource which was clicked, just the date.

Is there any way to get the resource also?

Thank you"

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the info about clicked resource existed inside the view data that you get from the dayClick event.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log(view);
}
```

Or if you use select for range it has the resource variable

```
select: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view, resource) {
    console.log(resource);
}
```